# How do I get Rust FFI to return array of structs or update memory?

Tags: c#, rust, ffi

Currently learning to use Rust FFI with C# and one of the of my problems at the moment is working with an array of struct `Item[]`.

What I'm trying to achieve is `C# => Rust => C#` I've been able to get the array into Rust and perform some operations on the data. What I'm stuck on is getting the result of saying a sorted Array from Rust back out to C#.

So what I assumed was that I could modify the memory directly from C# in Rust using pointers. However, despite being able to slice the data from the ptr and then sort the array in Rust, the result didn't propagate back into the C# scope.

I've also tried returning the array back to C# a return value, but my current knowledge of working with pointers from Rust back to C# is lacking, and I imagine it slightly more complicated since its a pointer to an array of struct.

Here a gist to a more flush out example. 
https://gist.github.com/Ostoyae/4511448776a4e54c0b4077883e761f11

lib.rs

```
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Item {
    id: *const c_char,
    name: *const c_char,
    variation: u32,
    category: u32,
    quality: u32,
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn ffi_sort_inventory(length: u32, array_ptr: *mut Item) {
    let items: &mut [Item] = unsafe {
        assert!(!array_ptr.is_null());
        std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(array_ptr, length as usize)
    }; 
        // some sorting to items //
}
```

rust_ffi.cs

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Item
    {
        public string id;
        public string name;
        public uint variation;
        public uint category;
        public uint quality;
    }

public class Inventory {
        private Item[] items;

        [DllImport("stuff")]
        [System.Security.SecurityCritical]
        private static extern void ffi_sort_inventory(uint length, Item[] items);

        public void sort_inventory()
        {
            ffi_sort_inventory((uint) Items.Length, this.items);

            WriteLine(items);
        }
    }
}
```

What I would hope the best case is to modify the array that already exists in memory by using a pointer instead of returning newly allocated memory. But i would also appreciate seeing both solutions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Item
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)]
        public string id;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)]
        public string name;
        public uint variation;
        public uint category;
        public uint quality;
    }

    public class Inventory {



        [DllImport("stuff")]
        [System.Security.SecurityCritical]
        private static extern void ffi_sort_inventory(uint length, IntPtr items);

        public void sort_inventory()
        {
             Item[] items = null;
             IntPtr itemsPtr =  IntPtr.Zero;
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(items, itemsPtr, true);
            ffi_sort_inventory((uint) items.Length, itemsPtr);

        } 
    }
```

Comment: Got an rrror when I tried to run my test involving `Marshal.StructureToPtr()` 

System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: ptr

Comment: You need to add items to the array before calling the method.  I set it to null to remove the compiler errors.